# Eclipse photon error installation process

Tags: java, eclipse

I was trying to install the new version and it keeps refusing and an error pops up with logs like this. I tried to uninstall it and redownload the launcher. Please give me specific directions to fix this. Here is what it looks like below:

[image]
This is the log when I tried to install it and the error.

Comment: Are you behind a company proxy, by chance?

Comment: Please don't post a image of the error. Use copy & paste it into the question

Comment: Just download the stand-alone package and do it manually? https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Comment: Maybe I don't know